# Download Image link using php

Tags: php, image, download

I downloaded this code to use as a download button.

```
<?    
    $filename = $_GET["filename"];
    $buffer = file_get_contents($filename);

    /* Force download dialog... */
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    /* Don't allow caching... */
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    /* Set data type, size and filename */
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($buffer));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

    /* Send our file... */
    echo $buffer; 
?>
```

The thing is, the name of the file ends up with the whole path in the file name, for example, this code:

```
<a href="download.php?filename=images/something.jpg">
```

Ends up with an image named "images_something.jpg"

I'd like to remove the "images_" from the final file name, so far I haven't had any luck.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: With that script anyone can download any file from your server, so I'd look into securing it before using it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, could you point me to a website where I could research how to seccure it?.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the file name part without folder name, you have to use basename($filename)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Answer (score 2):

[basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
$filename = basename($path);
```

p.s

Setting Content-Type several times may not be the best way to force a download. Also, I **hope** you're sanitizing that `$filename` argument before you use a file_get_contents.

p.p.s

Use [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), don't cache it in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
$filename = basename($filename); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
```

Set your filename to only be the basename?

Don't do it at the top unless you change the variables though so your pathing to it still works.